# Are Mu and Kiki Humans?

Tags: saint-seiya

Are these two characters from *Saint Seiya* regular human beings like Seiya? Or are they members of another race?

[image: Characters from Saint Seiya]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are. They just have psychic powers.

Answer (score 2):

It's unknown, although if they are not 100% human, they mostly are.

Both are supposed to be descendants of muvians, an ancient race that inhabited the continent of Mu, which is considered largely extinct.

That race had some natural ability for psychic powers without the use of cosmos, so as both can use them, it feels safe to assume that it's due to its natural genetic ability, not due  to cosmos, so in this sense you wouldn't call them  humans at 100%.

You can check that [here](https://saintseiya.fandom.com/wiki/Muvians).

Comment: Midchlorians...